# Azure WebJob ProcessQueueMessage fails to read CloudQueueMessage

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-storage-queues

In summary, I have an Azure Web Job linked to a `CloudQueue` via the WebJobs SDK's `ProcessQueueMessage` mechanism, using the `CloudQueueMessage` parameter type. This gives me a `FunctionInvocationException` when triggered via `QueueTrigger`.

---

**Detail**

The item is added successfully to the `CloudQueue` using the `AddMessageAsync` method:

```
await queue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject)));
```

And appears on the queue as the expected JSON representation of my object (from Message Text Preview in Cloud Explorer):

```
{"EmailAddress":"example@mail.com",
 "Subject":"Test",
 "TemplateId":"00-00-00-00-00",
 "Model":{"PropertyName1":"Test1","PropertyName2":"Test2"}
 }
```

However, when the `ProcessQueueMessage` method is triggered:

```
public static async void ProcessQueueMessage(
    [QueueTrigger(queueName)] CloudQueueMessage message, TextWriter log)
```

... I get a `FunctionInvocationException`:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Exception binding parameter 'message' ---> System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String.
 Parameter name: s
 at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueueMessage.get_AsBytes() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Queue\CloudQueueMessage.Common.cs:line 146
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.PropertyHelper.CallPropertyGetter[TDeclaringType,TValue](Func`2 getter, Object this)
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.PropertyHelper.GetValue(Object instance)
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.BindingDataProvider.GetBindingData(Object value)
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Triggers.UserTypeArgumentBindingProvider.UserTypeArgumentBinding.BindAsync(IStorageQueueMessage value, ValueBindingContext context)
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Triggers.QueueTriggerBinding.<BindAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Triggers.TriggeredFunctionBinding`1.<BindCoreAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DelayedException.Throw()
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
```

This seems to suggest that the `message` parameter is failing to read the JSON into the `CloudQueueMessage` object ... but it doesn't appear that it's something I have control of.

*Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be happening?*

---

**Version Info**

Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs 1.1.1

WindowsAzure.Storage 6.2.2-preview

DNX 4.5.1

**Background**

[Troy Hunt - Web Job primer](http://www.troyhunt.com/2015/01/azure-webjobs-are-awesome-and-you.html)

[MSDN - How to... article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/#trigger)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your ProcessQueueMessage to accept a string (which is what you actually passing to the CloudQueuMessage), then take that and deserialize it to your object:

```
public static async void ProcessQueueMessage(
    [QueueTrigger(queueName)] string message, TextWriter log)
{
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObjectType>(json);
}
```

Or event better, if this is a POCO object then all you have to do is to use that instead:

```
public static async void ProcessQueueMessage
(
   [QueueTrigger(queueName)] YourObjectType message, 
   TextWriter log
)
{      //....    }
```

**Update:**
Although it would be nice to get the entire thing in a CloudQueueMessage object, but to get the properties that is sent in the CloudQueueMessage you can add the following parameters to the webjob method:

```
public static async void ProcessQueueMessage(
        [QueueTrigger(queueName)] string logMessage, 
        DateTimeOffset expirationTime,
        DateTimeOffset insertionTime,
        DateTimeOffset nextVisibleTime,
        string id,
        string popReceipt,
        int dequeueCount,
        string queueTrigger,
        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount,
        TextWriter logger)
    {
        logger.WriteLine(
            "logMessage={0}\n" +
        "expirationTime={1}\ninsertionTime={2}\n" +
            "nextVisibleTime={3}\n" +
            "id={4}\npopReceipt={5}\ndequeueCount={6}\n" +
            "queue endpoint={7} queueTrigger={8}",
            logMessage, expirationTime,
            insertionTime,
            nextVisibleTime, id,
            popReceipt, dequeueCount,
            cloudStorageAccount.QueueEndpoint,
            queueTrigger);
    }
```

Comment: thanks @zaid. Both of your suggestions avoid the error. Using `CloudQueueMessage` would let me access properties of the message too (e.g. `InsertionTime`) and should be valid. From the referenced MSDN link: "Besides string, the parameter may be a byte array, a CloudQueueMessage object, or a POCO that you define."

Comment: @richaux, these properties can be added to the method parameters. You queue a CloudQueueMessage on the sender side but you get the content and metadata on the method parameters on the receiver end, see section "Get queue or queue message metadata" in the referenced Azure doc URL above. I'll update my answer to show that for completeness.

Comment: thanks for the example. Found some further background in the [github docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/Binding-Attributes) too.

Comment: Note that CloudQueueMessage isn't one of the listed supported input binding types (see [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=524028&clcid=0x409)), it's only supported as an out binding. I think that it could/should be an input binding, but not currently.

Comment: thanks @mathewc -- tbh I didn't find that the Quick Ref clarified matters :) It has `CloudQueueMessage` listed as an option for `QueueTrigger` binding at the top of the page, and the example in section 2.1 uses it too. The [article by Tom D referenced from the Quick Ref](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/#trigger) also has `CloudQueueMessage` as an option (but no example). It's not a problem: the POCO and string options are fine for my current needs.

Comment: Yes, good point, sorry for the confusion. If you think we have a bug, please log an issue in our public repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues